# Godot calling game over function twice

Tags: godot

So I had a node with  area_2d enemies. When a player hits any of the enemies, the `on_enemy_area_entered` signal calls the game over function which adds the coins collected during that game instance to the global coin variable and saves it. Nice and dandy...except if the player hits both at the same time. When that happens, the signal calls the `game_over` function twice and therefore the player sees double of his real score in the main menu....Due to the type of game it is I cannot prevent the player from hitting two enemies at the same time

What can I do

Comment: To make it short, have the object that is responsible for `game_over()` have a boolean variable called something like `has_game_ended`. At that top of `game_over()` check `has_game_ended`. If it's `true` return from `game_over()`.

Comment: when the player is hit, disable the collider (you can also disconnect the signal) and "kill" the player, then init a new player scene

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try something like this:

```
var is_game_over = false

func game_over():
    if not is_game_over:
        # your code to add coins etc.
        is_game_over = true
```

First, `game_over()` will check if the game's already over (`is_game_over` variable), if it's true, it'll do the work and in the end it will set the `is_game_over` variable to `true` to know that game is already over; and when your player hits the second enemy, the `game_over()` function will know that the game is over and won't add coins again.